# Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ping

I am using Linux laptop and try to ping a Win10 laptop. I ping myself (Linux system) and google.com, both works, which means the IP connection to router and DNS have no problem. But I still got 'Destination Host Unreachable' error. Please enlighten. Thank you.

```
root@imx8mnlego:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2156 (2.1 KiB)  TX bytes:2156 (2.1 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:E1:A1:E0:00:80
          inet addr:192.168.0.128  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3ee1:a1ff:fee0:80/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1894 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9943 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3000
          RX bytes:91940 (89.7 KiB)  TX bytes:2469289 (2.3 MiB)

root@imx8mnlego:~# ping 192.168.0.128
PING 192.168.0.128 (192.168.0.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.128: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.128: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.128 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2031ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.109/0.117/0.122/0.013 ms

root@imx8mnlego:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.194.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sfo03s01-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.194.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from sfo03s01-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.194.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from sfo03s01-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.194.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=19.3 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.101/17.579/19.375/1.810 ms

root@imx8mnlego:~#
```

Comment: thanks for your reminder, i copy and paste the text to my question.

Comment: Please edit your question and include an example of what you try that results in `Destination Host Unreachable`.

Comment: Edit your question and show  us the failing `ping` command and its output, and `ip route;ip address`

Answer (score 1):

"Destination host unreachable" means that there was no ARP response (in case of ethernet connection) at appropriate route exit point, which in case of your private LAN should be your Linux laptop ifself (i.e. both the laptops reside in the same network `192.168.0.0/24`), and if they are in distinct networks it is the router that doesn't either see the other side ...or filters the traffic. In both cases this might be the (WiFi) router that prevents peers to see each other - doing e.g. some "L2 filtering".

In order to diagnose such problems you can:

1. check ARP table of the pinging host,
2. check route table on both hosts,
3. install `wireshark` on both laptops and see which packets arrives and which are missing.

But first of all, give us the IP address of the Win10 laptop.